# How do i get contextmenu item font information like type dize ? And how do i change the item/s font size type?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In this code i create context menu with some items and then the last item i draw it.
I want that the last item that i draw it's font size and type will be the same like the 3 items before like the Cut Copy Paste.

How do i know what font style type size are the first items so i can change the last one to look like them ?

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                ContextMenu m = new ContextMenu();

                m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Cut"));
                m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Copy"));
                m.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Paste"));

                int currentMouseOverRow = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;

                if (currentMouseOverRow >= 0)
                {
                    m.MenuItems.Add(new CustomMenuItem(string.Format("Row number {0}", currentMouseOverRow)));
                    m.MenuItems[m.MenuItems.Count - 1].OwnerDraw = true;
                    m.MenuItems[m.MenuItems.Count - 1].DrawItem += Cm_DrawItem;
                    m.MenuItems[m.MenuItems.Count - 1].MeasureItem += MeasureMenuItem;
                }

                m.Show(dataGridView1, new Point(e.X, e.Y));

            }
        }
```

Then draw:

```
    void Cm_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        var item = (MenuItem)sender;
        var g = e.Graphics;
        var font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Italic);
        var brush = System.Drawing.Brushes.Red;
        g.DrawString(item.Text, font, brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
        font.Dispose();
    }
```

Then measure:

```
    void MeasureMenuItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem m = (MenuItem)sender;
        Font font = new Font(Font.FontFamily, Font.Size, Font.Style);
        SizeF sze = e.Graphics.MeasureString(m.Text, font);
        e.ItemHeight = (int)sze.Height;
        e.ItemWidth = (int)sze.Width;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what i was looking for.

```
var font = System.Drawing.SystemFonts.DefaultFont;
```